# Android use an Spinner from dialog

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-alertdialog

in my application i have one `AlertDialog` with an `Spinner` widget and i want to fill with any items. but i get this error :

```
Error:(100, 52) java: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(<anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener>,int,java.util.List<java.lang.String>)
    constructor android.widget.ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,int,int,java.util.List<java.lang.String>) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor android.widget.ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,int,java.util.List<java.lang.String>) is not applicable
      (actual argument <anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener> cannot be converted to android.content.Context by method invocation conversion)
    constructor android.widget.ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,int,int,java.lang.String[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor android.widget.ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,int,java.lang.String[]) is not applicable
      (actual argument <anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener> cannot be converted to android.content.Context by method invocation conversion)
    constructor android.widget.ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,int,int) is not applicable
      (actual argument <anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener> cannot be converted to android.content.Context by method invocation conversion)
    constructor android.widget.ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

My problem is fill attached `Spinner` in `AlertDialog`

[image]

Dialog xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layoutRoot" android:background="@null">

   <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner" android:spinnerMode="dropdown" android:layout_weight="0.80"/>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="New Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_weight="0.20"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fill into activity by clicking on button in class extends from Activity.

```
 bt_send_group.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ContactListActivity.this);
                View v = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_send_sms, null);
                builder.setView(v);
                final AlertDialog sms_dialog = builder.create();
                sms_dialog.show();

                Spinner panel_numbers = (Spinner) v.findViewById ( R.id.spinner );
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Android");
                list.add("Java");
                list.add("Spinner Data");
                list.add("Spinner Adapter");
                list.add("Spinner Example");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                        (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);

                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
                        (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                panel_numbers.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replcae this line of your code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
```

with this line

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (ContactListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
```